# nested Data binding in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maui

I have a ListView that utilizes the ItemsSource="{Binding CompletedChecklist}" property along with an ItemTemplate using x:DataType="model:CompletedChecklist"> DataTemplate. Within this list, my objective is to include a button (<Button Text="testing") inside each list item, which should have a different source for the command. Unfortunately, my current code isn't functioning as expected. Do you have any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
My other commands working fine, only this one doesn't work

does this command look good?

```xml
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CompletedChecklistsPage}, Path=BindingContext.ChecklistCommand}"
```

Entire code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:xxx.vvv.zzz.App.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:xxx.vvv.zzz.App.Converters"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:xxx.vvv.zzzz.Core.Models;assembly=xxx.vvv.ExternalDisplay.Core"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:xxx.vv.zzz.App.Views"
             x:Class="xxx.vvv.zzz.App.Views.CompletedChecklistsPage"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:DataType="viewModels:CompletedChecklistsViewModel"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BlackBackgroundColor}">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
            <xct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
            <converters:CheckedColorConverter x:Key="CheckedColorConverter" />
            <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid
        ColumnDefinitions="*"
        ColumnSpacing="20"
        RowDefinitions="50,*"
        Style="{StaticResource BaseGridStyle}">

        <!-- Top bar -->
        <views:TopBarView
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Padding="5">

            <Grid
                Grid.Row="1"
                HeightRequest="75"
                Padding="5"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WarningBackgroundColor}"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill"
                    Command="{Binding ChecklistCommand}"
                    Text="Do your checklist" />

                <Button
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WarningBackgroundColor}"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill"
                    Command="{Binding DelaysCommand}"
                    Text="Delays" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <!-- Adding Padding and Border around ListView -->
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="5">
                        <ListView
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CompletedChecklist}"
                            HasUnevenRows="True"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            SeparatorVisibility="None">

                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:CompletedChecklist">
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <!-- Adding Border for each item -->
                                        <Frame BorderColor="Black" CornerRadius="5" Padding="0">
                                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MenuBackgroundColor}" Padding="10">
                                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CompletedChecklistsViewModel}}, Path=BindingContext.ItemSelectedCommand}"
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label Text="Checklist Completed by Sina " TextColor="White" />
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding CompletedAt, StringFormat=' - {0:MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss}'}" TextColor="White" />

                                                    <Button Text="testing"
                                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CompletedChecklistsPage}, Path=BindingContext.ChecklistCommand}"
                                                        />
                                                </StackLayout>

                                                <!-- Adding a line between items -->
                                                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The class has a single property named Name of type string that you set to the name of an element on the page that has been given a name with x:Name. This Name property is the content property of ReferenceExtension, so Name= is not required when x:Reference appears in curly braces.

That means, you should set **x:Name** for the *CompletedChecklistsPage*, and in x:Reference set to the name of the *CompletedChecklistsPage*.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:xxx.vvv.zzz.App.ViewModels"
         ...
         x:Name="CompletedChecklistsPage">
```

And then use the binding for command like what you did:

```
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CompletedChecklistsPage}, Path=BindingContext.ChecklistCommand}"
```

Don't forget to set the BindingContext for the page, such like:

```
public CompletedChecklistsPage()
{
    ...
    this.BindingContext = new CompletedChecklistsViewModel();
}
```

Now the Command for Button binds to the **ChecklistCommand** in ViewModel.

For more info, you could refer to [x:Reference markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/markup-extensions/consume#xreference-markup-extension)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This can be solved using a properly formed relative binding.

Comment: @Julian Why shouldn't use the BindingContext like that?

Comment: First of all, it will be unclear from the binding expression that the binding is to a command of the `CompletedChecklistsViewModel`. Secondly, using the `x:DataType` attribute enables compiled bindings (provided that XAML compilation is enabled), but the type of `BindingContext` in this particular binding expression will only be known during runtime.

Comment: @Julian Thanks for response. I am not sure how much performance enhancement relative bindings can bring. But found no compile-time validation for relative binding.

Comment: And both two methods can solve this case. I think using x:reference expression sometimes is more flexible and universal I think. For example, we cannot use Relative binding for those who don't have unique visual tree parents. Besides, op's question is about binding expression. I just tell him why it doesn't work and how it can work.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9839

Comment: I agree that x:Reference generally is very useful, but not particularly when referring to the BindingContext. With regards to the bug you linked, that's new to me. I haven't encountered any such issues before and I've used relative bindings and compiled bindings quite extensively in XF and MAUI. In either case, it's good to have options to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Don't use the `BindingContext` like that in a binding expression. Instead, you can use a relative binding to your `CompletedChecklistsViewModel` by referencing it as an ancestor.

Change this:

```xml
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CompletedChecklistsPage}, Path=BindingContext.ChecklistCommand}"
```

to:

```xml
Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CompletedChecklistsViewModel}}, Path=ChecklistCommand}"
```

Likewise, you may want to change the following:

```xml
<TapGestureRecognizer
    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CompletedChecklistsViewModel}}, Path=BindingContext.ItemSelectedCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

to:

```xml
<TapGestureRecognizer
    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:CompletedChecklistsViewModel}}, Path=ItemSelectedCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

---

Relative Bindings for Xamarin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

Relative Bindings for MAUI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

## Option 2

Fix the binding expression by declaring the `x:Name` of the Page (you cannot use the same name as the type):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:xxx.vvv.zzz.App.ViewModels"
             x:Class="xxx.vvv.zzz.App.Views.CompletedChecklistsPage"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:DataType="viewModels:CompletedChecklistsViewModel"
             x:Name="MyChecklistsPage">
```

and then use that name with the `x:Reference` markup extension, similar to what Liqun Shen has mentioned:

```xml
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyChecklistsPage}, Path=BindingContext.ChecklistCommand}"
```

I don't recommend doing it like this, however. Option 1 works better with [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings), because the data type is known during compile time already, while the Option 2 will require a runtime resolution of the type that is used as the binding source in the binding expression.